# HOW TO: Schedule in crontab a Python script with Selenium driver to show chromium browser on DISPLAY :0.0

Tags: cron, chromium, selenium-webdriver

I would like run a specific moment a python script to show with selenium the chromium browser on DISPLAY :0.0 .

```
00 11 * * * pi export DISPLAY=:0.0 && "/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/script.py"
```

Example python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding=utf8
from selenium import webdriver

def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver",chrome_options=options)
    browser.get("www.google.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the command with the quotes can't work:

```
"/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/script.py"
```

It might work without the quotes

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/script.py
```

It depends on the X Server. It is likely that you will also need to set `XAUTHORITY`.

You can test this from the command line:

```
env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/script.py
```

If this works, then your command should work if you remove the quote.

Otherwise try

```
env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY" /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/script.py
```

If this works, you need to set `XAUTHORITY` to the value of `XAUTHORITY`.

You may also need environment variables related to Python, like `PYTHONSTARTUP`, `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: At the end:
`00 11 * * * env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/pi/Desktop/script.py `
It worked fine. Thanks